# Split server log strings into array and read as index, also grep for keywords

Tags: javascript

I'm able to select and read a local file using the code below:

Structure of my local file i'm reading looks like this.

```
27/03/19 12:36:18:193 LINE 1

27/03/19 12:36:18:198 LINE 2

27/03/19 12:36:18:198 LINE 3 LINE 3.1

27/03/19 12:36:18:199 LINE 4

27/03/19 12:36:18:199 LINE 5 LINE 5.1

27/03/19 12:36:25:045 LINE 6
```

My problem is I want to be able to split the file into an array and output parts as index

i.e.

```
#0|  27/03/19   #1|  12:36:18:199   #2|  LINE 5    #3|  LINE 5.1
data[2] = LINE 5
```

Also be able grep for a keyword and out put that .

Nb. the file is a server log so would need to be read in realtime.

Thanks in advance for your answers,
Cody

```
<img id='output'>
<script>
  var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      var text = reader.result;
      console.log(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: client-side javascript CANNOT read file in real-time as it needs user input to open and read local file. Also have tries using regular expressions to split the contents of the file?

Comment: So best using something like nodeJS right?

Comment: node.js is server-side technology, so it depends on what is your application and purpose of reading the log file. But yes node.js can do it in real-time

Comment: About splitting your file content, you should use regular expressions. With [`^((?:\d{2}\/?){3})\s+((?:\d{2}:){3}\d{3})\s+(.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/pXzf9T/1), you will be able to separate date, time and line content (with `line A` and `line A.B` in the same group). This regex can be updated if your lines have separators, in order to split `line A` and `line A.B`.

Answer (score 0):

### Reading Files

If it's a server log and you wish to handle this client side in *realtime* then you'll need to:

#### Server

- Create a nodejs server that watches your log file for any modifications which can be done with [fs.Watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) and provides a [socket connection](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node)

#### Client

- Create a [web socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) that receives notifications from your server whenever your log file has changed with the data sent (*note the server web connection library also offers a client side one which is supported on all browsers, check [their examples](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node#client-example) to understand quickly*)
- Whenever new data is sent simply call the script below and update your view

### Why create a separate server to handle this ?

- Well if you're not running a nodejs server already, then creating a nodejs server is quick and easy.
- It's a feature outside of what your main server is focused on doing

### Handling Log Data:

Partial implementation on how to read the contents of your log file. You'll need to determine a pattern to be able to seperate `LINE 5 LINE 5.1` as this current script simply splits on white spaces. If each `LINE` does not have any spaces then it'll work.

```js
const data = `
27/03/19 12:36:18:193 LINE 1

27/03/19 12:36:18:198 LINE 2

27/03/19 12:36:18:198 LINE 3 LINE 3.1

27/03/19 12:36:18:199 LINE 4

27/03/19 12:36:18:199 LINE 5 LINE 5.1

27/03/19 12:36:25:045 LINE 6
`

const res = data
.trim()
.split(/\n+/)
.map(line=>line.split(/\s/));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hey, do you have a full working script you can share as I tried to add your block of but not working.

Answer (score 0):

After parsing the file contends by line, you can try the below snippet to get the contends with index , Assuming the line separators are "white spaces".

```js
function parseContends(inputString){
  if(inputString != null){
    var string = inputString.match(/\S+/g) || [];
    var stringArray = new Array();
    for(var i =0; i < string.length; i++){
      stringArray.push(string[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(stringArray);
}

parseContends("27/03/19 12:36:18:198 LINE 3 LINE 3.1");
```

The Above Snippet has been updated in the Code Pen , You can see the output in console.

```
[https://codepen.io/redhatvicky/pen/QoXLYw][1]
```

Comment: Hey, do you have a full working script you can share as I tried to add your block of but not working.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how I can select and have my my file in read in realtime?

Comment: In the real time , If the log files has to be parsed . There are two approaches one is you write a small javascript snippet which can pick up the log files in a periodical format and then parse the file line by line to apply the logic of splitting based on the delimiter. The second approach is the below approach which @kemikofa has mentioned.